# How to get the message after the command Discord

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm coding a self-describing bot there you can make your own profile with a few sentences.

When you send "!describe" the bot will send you a dm with rules and some stuff.
This works but i want to save the incoming dm message from the user after the dm from the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the users that used the `!describe` command in a list or database (depending on your scale and use case).

Every time your bot receives a DM you can check the list.
Depending on whether the user is in there, you can

- either handle the message as an answer to your command (and maybe afterward remove the user from the list to have the possibility of issuing the command multiple times)
- or ignore it (or do whatever you want with messages from users that didn't enter the command beforehand).